# Accessing property from Json Array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq

I have following array:

```
{
   "customizedData":[
      {
         "key":"SubscriptionId",
         "value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      {
         "key":"OfferId",
         "value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      {
         "key":"SubscriptionName",
         "value":"DYNAMICS 365 BUSINESS CENTRAL TEAM MEMBER"
      },
      {
         "key":"Quantity",
         "value":"6"
      },
      {
         "key":"Status",
         "value":"Suspended"
      },
      {
         "key":"PartnerOnRecord",
         "value":"None"
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I access key the elements:

"key": "SubscriptionName",
"value": "DYNAMICS 365 BUSINESS CENTRAL TEAM MEMBER"

At the moment I use: `(string)t["customizedData"][2]["value"]`

Are there any better ways?

Comment: can you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it C#, did I guess correctly?

Comment: What library do you use to work with json? Is it Json.NET? Add tag please.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov its tagged c# so I would assume so ?

Comment: Is deserializing to a strong type like `public partial class KeyValueThing
    {
        [J("customizedData")] public List<CustomizedDatum> CustomizedData { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class CustomizedDatum
    {
        [J("key")]   public string Key { get; set; }  
        [J("value")] public string Value { get; set; }
    }` and simply filtering like `KeyValueThing.CustomizedData.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Key=="MyKey")` viable?

Comment: @DevlinPaddock - I added this tag.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ah my bad i didnt realize you could add tags like that. I will keep that in mind in the future

Comment: thanks for the comments, @xdtTransform, that would be one method but was wondering if there was another without creating the strong type.

Comment: @sajid , at the moment I use (string)t["customizedData"][2]["value"] at it works but was wondering if I could do a search for key: SubscriptionName instead of directly accessing the property through array index

Comment: Assuming you are using Json.net so that you can use `t.SelectToken("$.customizedData[?(@.key == 'SubscriptionName')]").SelectToken("value").ToString()`

Comment: @Stanza How about the issue? Does any of the answers below resolve your question, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Json.net and you don't want to create strong type for it so you can use [SelectToken with JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm):

```
t.SelectToken("$.customizedData[?(@.key == 'SubscriptionName')].value").ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nuget this could be done with a helper function. first use
`var jo = JObject.Parse(jsonContent);` to parse, and pass that to the helper function `GetValueFromJson(jo, "SubscriptionName", "customizedData")`, using this helper function:

```
    private string GetValueFromJson(JObject jo, string key, string rootKey)
    {
        var value = jo[rootKey].Children()
                                        .Where(i => i["key"].ToString() == key)
                                        .Select(i => i["value"].ToString())
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't bad, but I think it would be better to pass in the `JObject` as the first parameter.  Otherwise if you want to use the method multiple times on the same JSON for different keys you end up re-parsing the JSON each time.  Better to parse once and then extract, extract, extract.